# Conditionally display an Action depending on whether or not a player is connected

Tags: haskell, optional

Is there a nicer way to write the `maybeWhen` portion of `displayConnectionAction` ? I want to conditionally display an `Action` depending on whether or not the player is connected.

This bit of code is lifted from a wider system where there are multiple calls like `displayConnectionAction` (conditional actions built up by a `Reader GameState`), so I am not after any feedback around things like the `Reader` being overkill etc, more the implementation of the function `displayConnectionAction`, the actual code has 12+ functions like this, all generating `Maybe Action`s based off various bits of logic.

```
data Action = Action
  { actionLabel :: Text
  , actionUrl :: Text
  , actionPlayer :: Int
  }

data GameState = GameState
  { currentPlayer :: Player
  }

data Player = Player
  { playerId :: Int
  , playerName :: Text
  , playerConnected :: Bool
  }

displayConnectionAction :: Reader GameState (Maybe Action)
displayConnectionAction = maybeWhen not <$> isConnected <*> action
  where
    action =
      Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" <$> currentPlayerId

    isConnected =
      asks (playerConnected . currentPlayer)

    currentPlayerId =
      asks (playerId . currentPlayer)

maybeWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe b -> Maybe b
maybeWhen f a mb =
  if f a then mb else Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

It always looks a little odd when one has to 'invent' something that seems like it ought to be a common, built-in expression, so I can understand why you ask.

Please interpret any of the following as nothing but my humble attempt to share what I know about Haskell programming. I don't consider myself a Haskell expert, and I don't know if other people would consider any of the following idiomatic...

## Simplify maybeWhen

Is it necessary to pass both a predicate and a value (`a`) when the value itself turns out to be a Boolean value?

Would it make sense to simplify `maybeWhen` to something like the following?

```
maybeWhen' :: Bool -> Maybe b -> Maybe b
maybeWhen' b mb =
  if b then mb else Nothing
```

This would enable you to rewrite `displayConnectionAction` like this:

```
displayConnectionAction :: Reader GameState (Maybe Action)
displayConnectionAction = maybeWhen' <$> (not <$> isConnected) <*> action
  where
    action =
      Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" <$> currentPlayerId

    isConnected =
      asks (playerConnected . currentPlayer)

    currentPlayerId =
      asks (playerId . currentPlayer)
```

All of the function body (from `where` and down) is the same; only the composition is different.

Notice that it first maps `isConnected` with `not`, and the applies the projected value and `action` to the simplified `maybeWhen'` function.

## maybeWhen' is just a composition

Instead of writing a function like `maybeWhen'`, you can compose it from `bool` from `Data.Bool`:

```
Prelude Data.Bool> :t flip (bool Nothing)
flip (bool Nothing) :: Bool -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

Plugging that into `displayConnectionAction` means that you can now write it like this:

```
displayConnectionAction :: Reader GameState (Maybe Action)
displayConnectionAction = flip (bool Nothing) <$> isConnected <*> action
  where
    action =
      Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" <$> currentPlayerId

    isConnected =
      asks (playerConnected . currentPlayer)

    currentPlayerId =
      asks (playerId . currentPlayer)
```

Again, all code below `where` is the same. Notice, however, that you no longer need any helper function.

Or, instead of using the `flip` function, you could just flip the arguments:

```
displayConnectionAction :: Reader GameState (Maybe Action)
displayConnectionAction = bool Nothing <$> action <*> isConnected
  where
    action =
      Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" <$> currentPlayerId

    isConnected =
      asks (playerConnected . currentPlayer)

    currentPlayerId =
      asks (playerId . currentPlayer)
```

Notice that in this version, `action` and `isConnected` has changed places.

All this, however, relies on the simplification that in this particular example, the `a` in `maybeWhen` turns out to be `Bool`. Perhaps that's not always the case...

## Use do-notation

Personally, I think this would be more readable if you rewrite the function using `do` notation. There are definitely Haskell programmers who consider `do` notation a crutch that has 'nothing to do with functional programming', but I don't share that sentiment.

Since `Reader` is a `Monad`, you could refactor the function to this implementation:

```
displayConnectionAction :: Reader GameState (Maybe Action)
displayConnectionAction = do
  currentPlayerId <- asks (playerId . currentPlayer)
  let action = Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" $ currentPlayerId
  isConnected <- asks (playerConnected . currentPlayer)
  if not isConnected
    then return action
    else return Nothing
```

Instead of having various `Reader GameState` values that you need to figure out how to combine, a variable like `currentPlayerId` is now simply an `Int`, and `isConnected` is simply a `Bool`.

Ultimately, though, if you often find yourself short-circuiting `Bool` values to `Nothing`, you may want to consider using `guard`, `when`, and `unless` with the `Maybe` monad. In this case, though, this would require you to use a monad transformer so that you can either stack your `Reader` inside `MaybeT`, or stack `Maybe` inside `ReaderT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll stand on Mark Seemann's shoulders:

```
displayConnectionAction = withReader currentPlayer $ do
  connected <- asks playerConnected
  if connected
    then return Nothing
    else asks $ Just . Action "Connect" "/connect" . playerId
```

I wouldn't qualify field names with what records define them, it leads to redundant name dropping in compositions.

`MaybeT` (or equivalently `ReaderT r Maybe`) can do us one better:

```
displayConnectionAction =
  withReader currentPlayer $ runMaybeT $ do
    False <- asks playerConnected
    asks $ Action "Connect" "/connect" . playerId
```

With more context, next steps may include checking whether `Action` is consumed in only one place, and if so whether we can produce what it's turned into immediately. If a connected player means a presence of player data which would be obtained by the connection action, `<|>` could capture that pattern so we can get rid of that stinky boolean handling.